# cannot center element when used in columns in html

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 " style="border: groove;">
            <p class="circle col-xs-1 center-block">01</p>
            <h3>trending courses</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, consectetur?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3" style="border: groove;">
            <p class="circle text-center">02</p>
            <h3>books&library</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit nostrum voluptates tempore, pariatur nobis
                tempora repellendus deserunt suscipit, sed ex nihil eum impedit maiores quia modi qui aut velit
                veritatis quam deleniti? Quasi dolor, asperiores ut cumque laboriosam accusamus eveniet esse. Officiis
                quidem perferendis qui.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3" style="border: groove;">
            <p class="circle">03</p>
            <h3>certified teachers</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, consectetur?</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

1. Used bs-5,bootstrap.bundle.min.css
2. This is the below output for this code
   [image]

3. This is the code of css

```
.circle {
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            padding: 10px;
            background: purple;
            border: 3px solid #000;
            display: flex;
            
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            font: 28px arial, sans-serif;
            
        }
```

4. I tried various ways of flex, it did not work until I change margin

Please help me, why this is not working

Comment: Please select a correct answer if your problem was solved, so that this question can be closed and future viewers can benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text: center` on your `.circle` element can't work because it will only center text inside the element and not the element itself.
If what you want to center the circle then you have to set margin to auto for the element

.

Or if you want to do it using flexbox then you have to wrap your p element with a div which has `display: flex` and `justify-content: center` styles.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a flexbox-only solution:

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: purple;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font: 28px arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 " style="border: groove;">
    <!--  flexbox wrapper for circle -->
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <p class="circle col-xs-1 center-block">01</p>
    </div>
    <h3 class="text-center">trending courses</h3>
    <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, consectetur?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3" style="border: groove;">
    <!--  flexbox wrapper for circle -->
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <p class="circle text-center">02</p>
    </div>
    <h3 class="text-center">books&library</h3>
    <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit nostrum voluptates tempore, pariatur nobis tempora repellendus deserunt suscipit, sed ex nihil eum impedit maiores quia modi qui aut velit veritatis quam deleniti? Quasi dolor, asperiores
      ut cumque laboriosam accusamus eveniet esse. Officiis quidem perferendis qui.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3" style="border: groove;">
    <!--  flexbox wrapper for circle -->
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <p class="circle">03</p>
    </div>
    <h3 class="text-center">certified teachers</h3>
    <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, consectetur?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you wrap each circle with a flexbox that has `justify-content: center;`, any items in the flexbox will be centered horizontally.

**EDIT**: OP wanted to center paragraph text as well.

Comment: It works but why it doesn't work when d-flex property used in p tag

Comment: @KonduruPremsai Use the `text-center` Bootstrap property (`text-align: center;` CSS) for centering `p` and `h3` text. See the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Use it to **center all elements**:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `margin:auto` in css or `m-auto` in bootstrap

Using Css

```
.circle {
        margin:auto
    }
```

Using BootStrap add a class name to the div `m-auto`

```
<p class="circle text-center m-auto">02</p>
```

Comment: I said that it is working when margin is set to auto, but it is not working whatever I used of display things and even text-align.

Answer (score -1):

Using Flex

Add a class called `dop` to parent and `chi` to child circle

```
<div className="col-lg-3 dop" style={{ border: "groove" }}>
        <p className="circle text-center chi">02</p>
```

CSS:

```
.dop {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.chi {
  align-self: center;
}
```

Try This